# .setTimeout() fires two times

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function () {$('#messages').click(); }, 3000);
</script>
```

Unfortunately, it fires after 3 seconds passed, and then it fires again after another 3 seconds... Anyone have any idea why?

**Edit:** Okay, but now... If I replace the above code with below code, then it fires only once (ofc it happens instantly):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#messages').click();
</script>
```

Comment: Need more code. I assure this code as-is would only fire once. However, I bet your click code somehow restarts the timer or something.

Comment: i guess your portion of js script is executed twice

Comment: no repro: http://jsfiddle.net/kGtQF/.

Comment: @Lenny There's no way the click code can restart a timer that isn't stored. And if the click "restarted" the timer, it would be an infinite loop, not just occur twice.

Comment: @user2864740 Like I said, if the click code executed a timer that called the click event, it would be endless, not twice. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: One possibility would be that there is an other event handler added to `$(#message).on("click", [...])` after your snippet. In that case, you would think it's fired twice when in reality 2 different event handle are called one after the other and only 1 event happened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working example. You're code is correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/3HrCm/

```
setTimeout(function () { alert("here"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: If the code is correct then you shouldn't answer. The question should be closed or the OP has to provide more information.

Comment: no need to post an answer to say it's working fine...obviously OP has other issues

Comment: Yeah... But alert is not firing up twice... FML... Thank you anyway. :)